# Is there any map software that has api that can be called from c#?

Tags: c#, mappoint

Is there any map software that has api that can be called from c#?
I have coded a delivery application, and I need to query Addresses and show a map with the location and route. I also need it to be offline from the internet. I heard that I can use Mappoint or Autoroute.

Comment: Why would someone down-vote the question?

Comment: By offline do you mean not connected to any network at all, or just not connected to the internet?

Comment: By <<offline from the internet>> I mean not to be dependent on the internet, I need it to work without being connected to the internet. I don't want it to be dependent on some web service like google maps and bing maps has.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this? Services like google maps aren't going to go anywhere overnight and by using them you can always make sure you've got the most up to date data. There are sometimes reasons, especially in a corporate environment, but I'm not sure this is the case for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually there is a good reason , the software is going to operate in countries where internet is has not allways availiable 100%. The software is a delivery software for restaurants and cafeterias. That means when you have about 1500 calls per day for Orders and the internet is unavailiable, the staff will spend to much time typing the new Customer addresses. Thanks!

Comment: your important point is "offline-mode" yet you failed to mention this in your question title, so that's maybe the -1 (not me though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoRoute = "Streets&Trips" branded for Europe. These are cut down versions of Microsoft MapPoint. They lack some of the business plotting stuff, but they also lack an API.

MapPoint can be installed from disk and comes with its own road data. But you are limitd to North America and Europe - this coverage might be too limited for your requirements?

The only low cost alternatives would be to find an open source system like QuantumGIS (which I don't think has routing but I could be wrong) or pgRouting (routing extension for PostGIS) and use OpenStreetMap data. Other systems that can work for multiple countries (excepting MapPoint) are going to tend to be pricey.

Finally: Good reasons not to use Bing Maps and Google Maps? Both Google and Microsoft have changed their APIs on a fairly frequent basis due to innovation. They are becoming more stable, but do you want to re-write your application every 12-18 months?